# Unsecure Configuration null value is comes

Tags: dynamics-crm

Plugin parameter using configuration , I am passing unseure configuration as parameter to plugin but null value is come when I am apply profile to check ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFqgY.jpg)

```
public class AttachGrid :IPlugin
    {


        #region Secure/Unsecure Configuration Setup
        private readonly string _unsecureString;
        private readonly string _secureString;
        XmlDocument xmldoc;
        String ParentLookupName;
        ITracingService tracer;
        #endregion
        public AttachGrid(string unsecureString, string secureString)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(unsecureString))
            {
                try
                {
                    //_unsecureConfig = unsecureString;
                    xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmldoc.LoadXml(unsecureString);
                    ParentLookupName = PluginConfiguration.GetConfigDataString(xmldoc, "ParentLookup");



                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
                }

            }

        }
```

Pass the configuration

```
<Settings>
  <setting name="ParentLookup">
    <value>originatingleadid</value>
  </setting>
</Settings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it an issue while debugging using the profiler only? Did you enable Use custom value in the unsecure configuration maybe? [Screenshot here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-zQ6820J0ea4/U2tmSamSmVI/AAAAAAAAAKk/HLRuqu33DYI/s1600/profiler14.png) extracted from [here](http://mscrm-njl.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/how-to-use-plugin-profiler-to-debug.html).

Anyway, since I created [FakeXrmEasy](http://dynamicsvalue.com/get-started/overview) testing framework, I'm coding/debugging/testing my plugins locally from Visual Studio without having to use the profiler, or log traces in a real CRM instance. You can actually test your plugins even before deploying them. :)

If you go to the "How To Test a Plugin" section there is an example there about using unsecure and secure configurations too.

Hope it helps!

PS: The framework is MIT licensed so anyone can use it, for free.